# Entity Framework error, context has changed after Update-Database command has run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity

I'm very new to C# and visual studio development and not sure why I'm getting the aforementioned error. I'm running the below setup:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Entity Framework 6.0.0
- DotNet Framework 4.6.1

Below is my error:

> The model backing the '' context has changed since the
>   database was created.

I ran the update-database command in the package manager console, which updated the database previously, but I'm still getting this error. Just need to be pointed in the right direction to figure why I'd still be seeing this error.

Comment: Did you change a model? You may need to run `add-migration` and then run the `update-database`

Comment: @Scrobi  thanks, I was able to figure this out. When I ran the `update-database` command what was happening is it was updating a completely different database than the one I was expecting it to. So I ran the `update-database` command passing the connection string to the correct database as an argument.